# I am a cleaner. I apparently got water into an external powerpoint

Tags: electrical, water

I need a bit of advice from an electrician. I am a cleaner and was asked by the client to clean her external windows and get rid of any cobwebs. I washed the windows and hosed as many cobwebs as I could from the external brickwork. Later that night the client phoned me and said that they had no power in part of their home and did I wet any areas that I shouldn't have. I don't remember hosing any power points but I may have as I was concentrating on the large amounts of cobwebs and spiders. The client isn't from Australia so I explained that I may have blown a fuse. She said that they had an electrician out and it was more than just a fuse?? Would I have been responsible for damages more than a blown fuse??? She has guests coming tomorrow, hence the window cleaning, now she says the electrician can't get there until the following week, so her guests now have no power to their bathroom and spa. If it's my fault of course I'm happy to pay but I don't see how I could have caused more than a blown fuse even if I did get water into the point.  Please help as soon as possible. I've got to go back there in the morning.

Comment: Before taking any blame (paying) ensure this is not coincidental. Maybe the "guest spa/bath" isn't used often and whilst preparing for the guest visit they turned something on that tripped a breaker or GFI?

Comment: How long have they been without power at this point? What are they doing to restore power?

Comment: "She had the electrician out and it was more than just a fuse" but the electrician can't come til next week.  So presumably he's come once, but didn't have the time or parts to fix it.  Nothing you could have done with a hose could cause damage requiring multiple visits.  Sure maybe he needed to replace a part, but a competent service electrician probably would have most all common parts on his truck.  Don't get sucked into accepting the blame the client is trying to lay onto you.

Comment: I kind of hate to suggest it, but do you know for sure that power wasn't off in that part of the house before you cleaned?

Answer (score 1):

If you got water into an external power point, it might trip an RCCB (gfci, ground fault circuit interrupter in the US). I would say to look first for external power points near where you washed. Remove the cover plate and  blast the insides with a hair dryer, being careful not to overheat the power point. If the owner has no power at all, they will have to use an extension cord from a power point of the neighbor's house.

I had a roof leak cause a loss of power on one circuit by dampening an external power point on a circuit with a GFCI breaker. Until I could get the roof fixed,                    I removed the receptacle and wired the circuit straight through with twist on wire connectors pointed upward so they shed water.

If an external power point was not properly sealed, it is the home owner's fault not yours. But in future you should not use a strong stream of water to clean around windows. I think people have gone overboard about 'power washing' houses.

If there are no external power points near where you washed, look for power points inside near the windows and dry them with the hair dryer.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't power washing the house, I was merely hosing off the cobwebs from the underside of the roof overhang and the brickwork. So there would have been water dripping from the roof onto the power point.

Comment: An alternative to the hair dryer is to use the blower output of a shop vac or even a leaf blower

Comment: Your client has visitors coming. Is it possible that in preparing for her visitors she did something that caused the power to go out?

Comment: Are there any exterior light fixtures on the underside of the roof overhang? If there are and they are protected by a GFCI circuit breaker or receptacle, then that could be the cause of the interruption. Rereading the original question I see that the power loss in only in part of the house, so probably a single circuit or part of a single circuit is interrupted.  However, the electrician would have diagnosed that.

Comment: Yes Jim there was an outside light that had cobwebs around it and I did squirt it to get rid of them.

Comment: Is that light working? If that light is not working and is on a GFCI then that could be the point where moisture is causing the ground fault circuit interrupter to trip.  If so it might dry out without intervention, but the recovery might be reduced by drying out the box with a stream of air.

Comment: Is your client giving you any updates on the status of her power outage?

Answer (score 1):

External power outlets should be waterproof to a standard close to IP66 and include a waterproof cover. Only directly spraying  water on th should cause any water to penetrate. Water ingress could cause a circuit breaker to trip in the main panel. This is dealt with by letting the outlet dry and resetting the breaker switch from off to on

If the homeowner asked you to use a hose on or near outlets, some or all the responsibility ought to be theirs.

Comment: Sidenote -- are UK exterior outlets allowed/required to be drained in addition to being sealed?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I don't know. The reason I don't know is both interesting and annoying. In the UK the law enacted by Parliament says something to the effect that "electrical installations/work must be safe" and whoever does such work bears responsibility. In practice that means we must follow some well-defined scheme. In practice, almost the only one used is published by the IET/BSI: "17th Edition Wiring Regulations". Which costs £65 to purchase. As (a) Electrician is not my profession and (b) I think govt should make standards freely available - hence I rely on free sources of guidance

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick -- well, there's a legal food fight on b) over here (again!) too...